# Using sleep() delays all output

Tags: php

I've built an IRC bot using a PHP bot framework called Philip (https://github.com/epochblue/philip). When the command `!hello` is sent into the chat by anyone, the bot should say "hello..." into the channel, wait 45 seconds, say "foo", wait 15 seconds, then say "bar" (I know that doesn't make any sense, just trying to get this code to work).

Here's the code that I've tried so far:

**Attempt #1**

```
$bot->onChannel('/^!hello$/', function($event) {
    $event->addResponse(Response::msg($event->getRequest()->getSource(), "hello..."));
    $now = time();
    while ($now + 45 > time()) {

    }
    $event->addResponse(Response::msg($event->getRequest()->getSource(), "foo"));
    while ($now + 60 > time()) {

    }
    $event->addResponse(Response::msg($event->getRequest()->getSource(), "bar"));
});
```

**Attempt #2**

```
$bot->onChannel('/^!hello$/', function($event) {
    $event->addResponse(Response::msg($event->getRequest()->getSource(), "hello..."));
    sleep(45);
    $event->addResponse(Response::msg($event->getRequest()->getSource(), "foo"));
    sleep(15);
    $event->addResponse(Response::msg($event->getRequest()->getSource(), "bar"));
});
```

With both of those attempts, the bot will wait the full 60 seconds before outputting anything at all. So instead of sending one message, then waiting, then sending another message, then waiting, then sending a third message, it just waited all 60 seconds then sent messages.

Any idea as to how I can get this to work as I would like it to?

Thanks

Comment: Try http://www.php.net/flush after each message

Comment: I don't know the framework, but looking at the code (https://github.com/epochblue/philip/blob/master/src/Philip/Philip.php) it looks like you want to send separate responses using the `send()` method ("Actually push data back into the socket (giggity).").

Comment: @Reeno just tried that. Doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Do you use some kind of output buffering? Like Gzip compression?

Answer (score 0):

Sleep freezes the thread you are currently in.
You should either do the message sending on a new thread (and sleep there causing the main thread not to freeze) using "pthreads" or you should use a timer.

Comment: That still doesn't explain (at least so I understand) why the first message sent before sleep() is called doesn't show up until after the last sleep(). Is there a success response it should wait for before sleeping?

Comment: When sending the message it will actually be added to a "buffer". Because you are calling sleep, it will not get time to process this buffer.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the [`fwrite()`](https://www.php.net/fwrite) docs, it has the following tidbit:

> **Note**:
> Writing to a network stream may end before the whole string is written. Return value of fwrite() may be checked:

```
<?php
function fwrite_stream($fp, $string) {
    for ($written = 0; $written < strlen($string); $written += $fwrite) {
        $fwrite = fwrite($fp, substr($string, $written));
        if ($fwrite === false) {
            return $written;
        }
    }
    return $written;
}
```

So in your `Phillip::send` method, you could incorporate a similar solution to hold the method until the `fwrite` to the socket is completed and return a success boolean, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what your solution is. Can you write some (pseudo)code so I can see what you mean?